# Getting data from a column and pasting it in a row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to get the data from an original sheet named "Interface Boletagem" that is column C rows 6 to 28 and paste this data in a new sheet named "Boletador (Dados)" on the last blank row and in different columns. Basically transposing all the data from the original sheet.

I managed to make it work, but the current script is taking a long time to complete... Any tips on how to optimize it?

```
function submitDataInbound(){

  //declare a variable and set the reference of active google sheet

  var myGoogleSheet=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var shUserForm=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Interface Boletagem");

  var datasheet=myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Boletador (Dados)");

  //code to update the data on database sheet

  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();

  var columnToCheck = datasheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  function getLastRowSpecial(range){
    var rowNum = 0;
    var blank = false;
    for(var row = 0; row < range.length; row++)

    if(range[row][0] === "" && !blank){
      rowNum = row;
      blank = true;
    }else if(range[row][0] !== ""){
      blank = false;
    };
    return rowNum; 
  };

  var blankRow=getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck) + 1;
  
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C26").getValue());//ID

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C27").getValue());//DF

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C11").getValue());//VMN

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C12").getValue());//VME

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C21").getValue());//Dea

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C22").getValue());//PS

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,7).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C23").getValue());//LSBD

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,8).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C24").getValue());//SS
    
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,9).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C20").getValue());//TID

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,10).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C6").getValue());//Cli

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,11).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C28").getValue());//CV

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,12).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue());//Moe

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,13).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C16").getValue());//TFX

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,14).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C8").getValue());//QtME
  
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,15).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C9").getValue());//TxBco

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,16).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C10").getValue());//TxCli

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,17).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C14").getValue());//IOF

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,18).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C13").getValue());//Tar

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,19).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C17").getValue());//BPar

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,20).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C19").getValue());//Nat

 datasheet.getRange(blankRow,21).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C18").getValue());//CBPar

  datasheet.getRange(blankRow,22).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C15").getValue());//IR

  ui.alert('Boletado')

  shUserForm.getRange("C6").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C7").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C8").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C9").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C10").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C11").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C12").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C13").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C14").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C15").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C16").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C17").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C18").clear();
  shUserForm.getRange("C19").clear();   

  shUserForm.getRange("C6").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C7").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C8").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C9").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C10").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C11").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C12").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C13").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C14").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C15").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C16").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C17").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C18").setBackground('#BEBEBE');
  shUserForm.getRange("C19").setBackground('#BEBEBE');

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the process cost of your script.

In this case, how about the following modification? In order to retrieve the values from the scattered cells, I used Sheets API. And, in order to clear and set background to the cells `"C6", "C7", "C8", "C9", "C10", "C11", "C12", "C13", "C14", "C15", "C16", "C17", "C18", "C19"`, `shUserForm.getRange(6, 3, 14).clear().setBackground('#BEBEBE')` is used.

#### Modified script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Sheets API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

```js
function submitDataInbound() {
  var myGoogleSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var shUserForm = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Interface Boletagem");
  var datasheet = myGoogleSheet.getSheetByName("Boletador (Dados)");
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var columnToCheck = datasheet.getRange("A:A").getValues();

  function getLastRowSpecial(range) {
    var rowNum = 0;
    var blank = false;
    for (var row = 0; row < range.length; row++)
      if (range[row][0] === "" && !blank) {
        rowNum = row;
        blank = true;
      } else if (range[row][0] !== "") {
        blank = false;
      };
    return rowNum;
  };

  var blankRow = getLastRowSpecial(columnToCheck) + 1;
  var ranges1 = ["C26", "C27", "C11", "C12", "C21", "C22", "C23", "C24", "C20", "C6", "C28", "C7", "C16", "C8", "C9", "C10", "C14", "C13", "C17", "C19", "C18", "C15"];
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.batchGet(myGoogleSheet.getId(), { ranges: ranges1.map(e => `'Interface Boletagem'!${e}`) }).valueRanges.map(({ values }) => values[0][0]);
  datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1, 1, values.length).setValues([values]);
  ui.alert('Boletado');
  shUserForm.getRange(6, 3, 14).clear().setBackground('#BEBEBE');
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.batchGet](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/batchGet)

Comment: Thanks! It did work... I edited my initial question to add more points that could be optimized as well. Any tips on how to use Sheets APIs for that?

Comment: @user18433675 About `I edited my initial question to add more points that could be optimized as well. Any tips on how to use Sheets APIs for that?`, please don't change your question. Because my proposed answer is your initial question. First, please resolve your initial question. When you have another question, please post it as a new question. Because when you change your question, it confuses other users. So I updated your question to your initial question.

Comment: Sorry @Tanaike, I have created a new question. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @user18433675 Thank you for your response. I would like to check it.

Comment: this is the link for the new question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71439241/reducing-process-cost-of-a-script